# How i can reduce this polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2 [x]$?

Tags: ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

How i can reduce the polynomial $f(x) = x^9+x^8+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2 [x]$. I've tried use the reduction modulo a prime, but that don't solve the problem totally.

Comment: Trial division by the handful of polynomials up to degree 4 solves the problem. You are lucky: all factors have degree $<4$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, so, i need suppose that the polynomial is reducible and see if some polynomial of degree $<4$ is a factor?

Answer (score 1):

Using [sage](http://www.sagemath.org) the factorization is easy:

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(2))
sage: f = x^9 + x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + 1
sage: f.factor()
(x^3 + x^2 + 1) * (x^3 + x + 1)^2
```

(Assuming that "reduce" means "factor" in the OP.)
Manually, as a human, we expect factors - if any - till degree four. So it is a good try to see if one of the factors

- $x$, $(x+1)$,
- then $(x^2+x+1)$, the only irreducible polynomial in degree two,
- then $(x^3+x+1)$, $(x^3+x^2+1)$, the only irreducible polynomials in degree three,
- and finally $(x^4 + x + 1)$, $(x^4 + x^3 + 1)$, $(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$, the only irreducible polynomials in degree four

divides the given polynomial.

Comment: And I guess you’re saying that once one knows the list of irreducibles that you’ve given, one hardly needs sage to get the factorization that you present.